# How can I create a proxy to view a job on AWS Glue's Spark UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I'm running Spark jobs on AWS Glue and I see the URLs to the YARN Web UI (the tracking URLs).

I'm not clear on how I can create a proxy to view that tracking site, which I'm hoping to use to find my way to the Spark UI to monitor the progress of my jobs.

Is there a way to accomplish this, like I would do for EMR?

Comment: @stefanobaghino I'm looking for the same. any fixes/settings?

Comment: You should probably ask the OP, @Josh Marcus.

Comment: No, it is not supported in Glue so far. You can use job metrics but it is kind of limited.

Comment: I've tried and failed at doing this several times. Makes Glue development incredibly difficult for anything but trivial jobs

Answer (score 1):

Support for SparkUi in Glue is finally added :-) - Release date: 19-Sept-2019

Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui.html